# OutputStream to byte[]

Tags: java, pdf, byte, blob, outputstream

the objective I'm trying to reach is to save a PDF into an Oracle database into a BLOB.
Currently, the servlet i'm using only sends back a pdf via HttpServletResponse.

`Printers.getPDFPrinter(0).printToResponse(myTemplate, response, 0, TemplateA.PDF);`

I don't have access to printToResponse script, so I don't know what it does. 
All I know is that response has a HttpServletResponse type from which I can get the OutputStream, and myTemplate implements an IDocument Interface which I have not access either.

If I could get either myTemplate or response into a byte array (in order to save it as a blob), it would be OK. 
However, in all my searches, I only found code to create a byte array from an input stream, and not an output stream.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: You should probably implement a descendent of `IDocument` that prints to a memory stream (which is an input/output stream), pass that as the template, and read it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which library the servlet uses accessing `Printers.getPDFPrinter(0)` but:

- the library may offer other methods than `printToResponse` (`printToStream`, `printToFile`, ...?)
- you may pass your own `HttpServletResponse` returning an dummy [ServletOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html) on `getOutputStream()`. This dummy subclass has to implement [write(int b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) by delegating to the result of [Blob.setBinaryStream(1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBinaryStream%28long%29).

If you want to write your own [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html), I would prefer inheriting from `HttpServletResponseWrapper` if the servlet should also return the PDF your `ServletOutputStream` needs to delegate the original and the Blob stream.

If you wand the servlet just to return an id to retrieve the PDF from the database later, you need to implement your own `HttpServletResponse`. In this case I would use a `Proxy` and the `InvocationHandler` handles `getOutputStream()`.

Comment: There was actually a printToStream method.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

That code probably requires the full HttpResponse because it also needs to set the content-type and some other bits. For as awful as it may sound, you can create a "mock" response object and override the relevant methods in order to intercept its writes to the output stream. You can provide the PDFWriter a ByteArrayOutputStream so that you can then get the byte[] and write it into your DB.